# Child elements starting opacity while using velocity.js and blast.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations, velocity.js

I have a simple wrapper div that I animate in using `velocity.js` UI pack. In the complete callback function, I am using a combination of `UI pack` and `blast.js` to animate three sentences.

The problem is that my sentences are initially shown, and only after that they are animated. They shouldn't be visible after the wrapper div is animated into view.

Everything is working fine if I don't animate the wrapper div, guess the opacity settings during animation are messing with child elements.

```
$('.wrap').velocity('transition.slideUpIn', {
    delay: 1000,
    display: null, 
    complete : function(){
      $(".animated")
      .blast({ delimiter: "character" })
      .velocity("transition.fadeIn", { 
        display: null,
        duration: 1000,
        stagger: 60,
        delay: 400
      }); 
    }
})
```

Here is the fiddle to see the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/vcsr6aqj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `p` tags aren't at `opacity: 0`, but only their characters, which are inside a `span` having as class `blast`. Since your invisible characters are only created when you call `$(".animated").blast({ delimiter: "character" })`, which means once your wrapper has completed its apparition, the sentences will be visible until then. So you have two possibilities that I can think of.

1. Create your span characters with `blast` at the page load, instead at the wrapper velocity complete and then call velocity on your created spans:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".animated").blast({ delimiter: "character" });
       $('.wrap').velocity('transition.slideUpIn', {
           delay: 1000,
           display: null, 
           complete : function(){
               $(".animated .blast").velocity("transition.fadeIn", { 
                   display: null,
                   duration: 1000,
                   stagger: 60,
                   delay: 400
               }); 
           }
       })
   });
   ```

   [**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/vcsr6aqj/5/)
2. Add a class to your `p` tags having `opacity: 0`:

   ```
   <p class="animated no-opacity">Sentence number one.</p>
   <p class="animated no-opacity">Sentence number two.</p>  
   <p class="animated no-opacity">Just one sentence more.</p>
   ```

   CSS:

   ```
   .no-opacity {
       opacity: 0;
   }
   ```

   When your wrapper has completed the velocity, remove the class from your `p` tags. Also, remove `delay: 400` from your velocity attributes, otherwise the sentences will show for `400` milliseconds:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.wrap').velocity('transition.slideUpIn', {
           delay: 1000,
           display: null, 
           complete : function(){
               $animated = $(".animated");
               $animated.removeClass("no-opacity");
               $animated.blast({ delimiter: "character" })
                        .velocity("transition.fadeIn", { 
                           display: null,
                           duration: 1000,
                           stagger: 60
                        });  
           }
       })
   });
   ```

   [**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/vcsr6aqj/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcsr6aqj/6/)). I'm sure there are more elegant solutions.

It appears that the slideUpIn animates `opacity` from 0 to 1, including the opacity of `.animated` which is probably 'inherited'. Setting it to 0 to hide it fixes it, but then `.blast()` doesn't work, so we enable it again.

Comment: Same as my answer, except instead of moving a line of JS and changing another, changing 3 lines of HTML and adding 3 lines of CSS, mine only adds 2 lines of JS, consistent with the JS context 'fadeIn' etc.. That'll be important later. Just sayin'. ;-)